# Issue with GitHub Raw Content URL: 404 Not Found

Tags: url

I'm encountering an issue with accessing raw content from my GitHub repository using the raw content URL. Here are the details:

- **GitHub Username:** Grynome
- **Repository Name:** Library
- **Branch:** main
- **File Path:** roc-labs.png

I've followed the correct format for the raw content URL, but I'm consistently receiving a 404 Not Found error. I've confirmed that the file exists in the specified branch and path within my repository. Additionally, the repository is public, and I'm not using any access tokens in the URL.

- The repository is public.
- The file is present in the **`main`** branch at the specified path.

I expected that the raw content URL "[https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Grynome/Library/main/roc-labs.png](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Grynome/Library/master/roc-labs.png)" would display the image without any issues. However, I'm consistently getting a 404 Not Found error. I appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it.

Comment: Looks like GitHub's URLs are case sensitive. Your image has extension `.PNG` instead of `.png`

Comment: ahh i see, yeah you right. thanks